# Unknown symbol in module / v7_flush_dcache_all undefined in linux kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to create a linux kernel module that will disable the data cache. I'm trying to use the v7_exit_coherency_flush(all) function in arch/arm/include/asm/cacheflush.h, and this function calls v7_flush_dcache_all, which I found is in arch/arm/mm/arch-v7.S.

My issue is that when I try to make my module, I get a warning

```
WARNING: "v7_flush_dcache_all  [/home/pi/Documents/ARMHammer/kern/my_kernel/cache_disable.ko] undefined!
```

and when I try to insert the module I get an error

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module cache_disable.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

So it looks like that ach-v7.S file isn't being read. I tried simply including it in my main file, but that produced a lot of errors, probably because its an assembly file.

I'm pretty much stuck at this point, is there someway I can include the assembly file in the Makefile, or maybe I'm not including all of the necessary .h files?

For what its worth, here's my main file

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>    /* For current */
#include <linux/tty.h>      /* For the tty declarations */
#include <linux/version.h>  /* For LINUX_VERSION_CODE */
#include <linux/mm.h>

#include <asm/cp15.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include <asm/glue-cache.h>
#include <asm/shmparam.h>
#include <asm/cachetype.h>
#include <asm/outercache.h>

// #include "my_cache-v7.h"


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Peter Jay Salzman");


static void print_string(char *str)
{
    struct tty_struct *my_tty;
    #if ( LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,5) )
        my_tty = current->tty;
    #else
        my_tty = current->signal->tty;
    #endif

        if (my_tty != NULL) {
            ((my_tty->ops)->write) (my_tty, /* The tty itself */
    #if ( LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,9) )     
                           0,   /* Don't take the string 
                               from user space        */
    #endif
                           str, /* String                 */
                           strlen(str));    /* Length */
    #if ( LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,9) )     
            ((my_tty->ops)->write) (my_tty, 0, "\015\012", 2);
    #else
            ((my_tty->ops)->write) (my_tty, "\015\012", 2);
    #endif
    }
}

static int __init print_string_init(void)
{
    v7_exit_coherency_flush(all);

    print_string("The module has been inserted.  Hello world!");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit print_string_exit(void)
{
    print_string("The module has been removed.  Farewell world!");
}

module_init(print_string_init);
module_exit(print_string_exit);
```

and my Makefile

```
obj-m += cache_disable.o
KDIR = /home/pi/linux/
all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Also, if anybody knows an easier way to disable the cache, I'm all ears!

Comment: Looks like the macro `v7_exit_coherency_flush` is not intended for being called by the module. Only kernel and drivers compiled into it may use that macro. Note, that for being callable from the module functions need to be exported (`EXPORT_SYMBOL`). As for including, `.S` files are not intended for being included. Instead, you may copy it and compile alongside with your module.

Comment: It is an internal function that is normally only called through [proc](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/proc-v7.S?id=refs/tags/v4.9-rc5#n542) mechanism.  The particular ARM version will be tied to a specific ARM CPU type.  Linux drivers/modules are meant to run on all hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v7_exit_coherency_flush()` is for power management code to take a CPU out of the kernel cleanly in order to power it off - it's not callable from random modules for very good reason. If you really want to lose data and crash the machine in weird and subtle ways, you might as well just bypass kernel functions entirely and use a trivial inline asm to hit the SCTLR directly<sup>*</sup>.

I dread to imagine what you're trying to achieve, but if you really want to run Linux (painfully slowly) with the cache off, you'll need to rebuild the kernel, turning off CONFIG_SMP in order to turn on CONFIG_CPU_DCACHE_DISABLE. That's the only vaguely supported method which might work.

<sub>* I'm not even going to explain that, it's that terrible an idea.</sub>